# powershell base64 encoding different results

Tags: powershell, base64

*below are the two commands for same purpose of doing a base64 encoding of a credtial.*

**from windows commandline :**

```
powershell "[convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes(\"ATSxxx0101:urSY13sm\"))"
```

**result**  `QVRTVFNHMDEwMTp1clNZMTNzbQ==`

**from powershell :**

```
[Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes('ATSxxx0101:urSY13sm'))
```

**result :** `QQBUAFMAVABTAEcAMAAxADAAMQA6AHUAcgBTAFkAMQAzAHMAbQA=`

result from windows command line , is working fine but the result powershell is wrong . but my tool can accept only the powershell command . direct windows command is not working. any idea experts ?

Comment: In first example you use`UTF8.GetBytes` Second is `Unicode.GetBytes`. Change second to `[Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes('ATSxxx0101:urSY13sm'))`

Comment: am really sorry , i did not note it. i was analysing for more than an hour but couldnt find  this. can you post in answer section . you are absolutely right.  i will mark as solved. or else anyway to remove this question ? i will try to not repeat this silly mistakes here.

Comment: No worries, we all sometimes need a fresh mind to look at a problem ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that `[Text.Encoding]::UTF8` is not the same as `[System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode`. The difference is not missing `System` but UTF/Unicode.

`Encoding.Unicode` [gets an encoding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.unicode?view=netframework-4.8) for the UTF-16 format using the little endian byte order.

`Encoding.UTF8` [gets an encoding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.utf8?view=netframework-4.8) for the UTF-8 format.